# class.pdf2txt doesn't work with tabular PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I've a stack of PDF containing tables with text inside them.

I've tried to scrap the text from them and perform a regex on the result but the **pdf2txt** class seems to not work with my .PDFs...

The output is blank and I don't get any error in the PHP logs.
Using the example .pdf provided with the class instead everything works fine.

I'm just using the plan example provided with the class:

```
require 'pdf2txt.php';

$file = 'myexample.pdf';

$a = new PDF2Text();
$a->setFilename($file);
$a->decodePDF();

echo $a->output();
```

The file tree is:

```
decodepdf.php
myexample.pdf
```

There are some limitations with this class or am I doing something wrong?

**N.B. I've successfully converted them in text using a VisualBasic class, so I don't think the problem are the .pdf**